# Field extension of one element

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let's say $F$ is a field and $\alpha\notin F$. I'm slightly confused about field extensions, but then would $F(\alpha)$ be
$$
\{a_1 + a_2\alpha: a_1,a_2\in F\}
$$
I know that now we can consider $F(\alpha)$ as a vector space over $F$. So, then, if my interpretation of $F(\alpha)$ was correct, would $[F: F(\alpha)] = 2$ because $1_F, \alpha$ would be a basis of $F(\alpha)$?

Edit: Wait no, I just realized this must be wrong. Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ isn't $\{a_1+ a_2\sqrt[3]{2}: a_1, a_2\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. I'm still confused on how to estimate the degree of a field extension, then, without knowing which field you're working in and what element you're extending it by.

Comment: For example, $\mathbb C=\mathbb R[i]$

Comment: But $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2) = \{a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]4 : a,b,c \in \mathbb Q\}$.

Comment: Depends.  What's the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$?  If it's $2$, then what you wrote.  If it's finite, so an algebraic field extension, you need more powers of $\alpha$ in your general term.  If it's infinity, so transcendental, you need all the powers.

Comment: This depends on whether $\alpha$ is algebraic of degree $2$ on $F$. For instance, it is false if $F=\mathbf Q$ and $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$, or $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few questions here bundled together. Let's consider a few in turn.

> Fix a field $F$ and an element $\alpha \not \in F$. Then is it true that $F(\alpha) = \{ a + b \alpha : a, b \in F \}$?

This is not true. The comments and edit indicate a concrete example $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. A more indicative example might be $\pi$, or the indeterminate $X$, as then both $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ are infinite dimensional as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$.

> Without knowing which field you're working in and what element you're extending it by, can you estimate the degree of a field extension?

As shown by the examples above, you cannot. For example, extending $F$ by $X$
is an infinite dimensional extension if $F = \mathbb{Q}$, but is a degree $2$ extension if $F = \mathbb{Q}(X^2)$.

This is very very nontrivial for transcendental extensions.Even with concrete elements, we don't know how to determine degrees of extensions. For example, if we let $F = \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$, then it is unknown whether $F(\zeta(3))$ is a finite degree extension or not.

> I'm still confused on how to estimate the degree of a field extension.

Without any additional information, you can't make informed estimates on the degree of a field extension. However, there are a few common scenarios where better estimates are possible.

The primary example is when this all takes place in a known field. For example, if $K$ is a degree $n$ field extension over a ground field $F$, and $\alpha$ is some element in $K$ but not in $F$, then the degree of $F(\alpha)$ is at most $n$. And more generically if $\overline{F}$ is the algebraic closure of $F$ and $\alpha \in \overline{F}$ but $\alpha \not \in F$, then $F(\alpha)$ has finite (but possibly very large) degree.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $\alpha $ must be algebraic, that means that there exists a polynomial P with coefficients in F such that $\alpha$ is a root of P. Denote $n=degP$, and suppose that P is irreductible (since the polynomial ring $F[X]$ is UFD), then $F(\alpha)$ is an F-vector space of dimension $n$ and generated by {$1_{F}, \alpha, \alpha^{2},..., \alpha^{n-1}$}.